# android RecyclerView same data overwritten [Not duplicate]

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am checking how **RecyclerView** works and I am stuck with a problem.The data is loaded into the **RecyclerView** in order when it is not scrolled,but when scrolled the same data are overwritten.So i created an **Arraylist** and added the position to **Arraylist** in **onBindViewHolder** and included a condition which checks if the position is not added in the **Arraylist**. If so then the data is written to the **TextView**.In the if condition I included a Log to check if it is loading.The Log is not shown but the data are mixed up this time when scrolled up or down.The **RecyclerView** data is an arraylist of numbers(0-149).I have checked similar questions in stackoverflow but it did not help me.

[image]

SampleRecyclerAdapter.java:

```
public class SampleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder> {
    View view;
    ArrayList arrayList;

    @Override
    public SampleRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_lyt,parent,false);
        if (arrayList==null){
            arrayList=new ArrayList();
        }
        return new RecyclerHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SampleRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("Position",Integer.toString(position));
        if (arrayList.size()>0&&!arrayList.contains(position)){
         holder.textView.setText(Data.getInstance().getData(position));
        arrayList.add(position);
            Log.e("Loaded","Loaded");
        }
         else if (arrayList.size()==0){
            holder.textView.setText(Data.getInstance().getData(position));
          arrayList.add(position);
            Log.e("Loaded","Loaded");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Data.getInstance().arrayList.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
    public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please if you did not understand let me know

Comment: **DO NOT** modify the collection being managed by your `RecyclerView.Adapter` (e.g., `arrayList.add()`) without telling the adapter about the change (e.g., `notifyDataSetChanged()` or more fine-grained methods).

Comment: Why are you tracking the positions `onBindViewHolder()` is called with? You shouldn't be basing any logic on that. All you need in that method is `holder.textView.setText(Data.getInstance().getData(position));`.

Comment: Mike, But when scrolled up and down wouldn't the same data be set to the TextView again?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid that

Comment: Please upload an answer

Comment: Not really. That is, the same data won't be set to the same `TextView` over and over again, if that's what you're getting at. `RecyclerView` recycles its `View`s. It keeps only as many as you can see on-screen, plus one or two more to keep things smooth. Overly simplistic description: imagine you're scrolling item 10 off-screen, and item 4 is coming in from the top. The `RecyclerView` is going to take the item 10 `View` and pass it to `onBindViewHolder()` with position 4. You now need to set the text to item 4, because it'll still have item 10's data. Follow me?

Comment: yes.So what if we have to load images.

Comment: Since the item 10th view is passed to onBindViewHolder at position 4 shouldn't I set the image that I earlier set to view at position 4 again.

Comment: Yeah, basically the same deal. Just set the correct image for the given position. There are libraries available that will take care of caching images for you, if needed; e.g., Picasso, Glide, etc.

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView is as its name suggests reuses the views, so it doesn't have to recreate all the views that is visible to the user.

Try this, I have not tested it but it should work:

```
public class SampleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder> {
    View view;
    FragmentActivity fragActivity;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;    

    public SampleRecyclerAdapter (FragmentActivity fragActivity, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.fragActivity = fragActivity;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }   

    @Override
    public SampleRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_lyt,parent,false);    

        return new RecyclerHolder(view);
    }   

    public void dataSetChanged() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SampleRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));   

    }   

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }   

    public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        }
    }
}
```